# Keyword not supported: 'data source' web.config

Tags: c#, web-config, database-connection, connection-string, datasource

I cant seem to see where the problem is in my connection string, where you have the " in the string I've even tried adding single quotes as advised on stackoverflow but it still doesn't seem to do anything.

Below is my connection strings, taken out and renamed the actual information for security reasons;

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=IP ADDRESS;Initial Catalog=DB NAME;integrated security=False;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERID;Password=PASSWORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ENTITYNAME" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelName.csdl|res://*/ModelName.ssdl|res://*/ModelName.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=IPADDRESS&quot;Data Source=IP ADDRESS;initial catalog=DB NAME;integrated security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />      
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: It seems that you have the ip address twice in the second connection string?

Comment: @Guffa good spot there! Schoolboy error. Amended the connection string and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part of your connection string appears to be the source of the problem:

```
...provider connection string=IPADDRESS&quot;Data Source=IP ADDRESS;...
```

The `IPADDRESS&quot;Data` should simply be `&quot;Data`. Your `IP ADDRESS` value appears *twice*; one of which (the one before the quote ["&quot;"]) is making the connection string invalid.

Your web.config entry should be:

```
<add name="ENTITYNAME" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelName.csdl|res://*/ModelName.ssdl|res://*/ModelName.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=IP ADDRESS;initial catalog=DB NAME;integrated security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: yep - just amended the problem before you had posted this - you're 100% correct. Idiotic mistake made by me. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

IP ADDRESS looks wrong, normally if using say sqlexpress the connection string would be:

"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS ....

for the local version or you may need to replace the "." with the machine name or local ip-address (assuming a development environment)